# Django - save form into database

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hey guy I need your help

so I have this model:

```
class PreferedShops(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shops, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username, self.shop.name
```

and this is the form:

```
class LikeShopForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PreferedShops
        fields = ['date_posted']
```

and this is the view:

```
def shops(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LikeShopForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            u = form.save(commit=False)
            u.user = request.user
            u.shop = request.shop
            u.save()
            return redirect('shops')
    else:
        form = LikeShopForm()
    return render(request, "shops.html", {'form': form})
```

the probleme that I have is when I click on Like Button, I want that the form takes automatically the user and the name of the shop, and then save them into the DB
the user and the shop's name should be hidden
when I click submit I have this error **'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'shop'**

please help me to take the shop's name automatically and save it in the db

Comment: Well why do you think that `request.show` would work? This is not part of the request, so you will need to *encode* it in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well the shop is *not* part of the request (strictly speaking, `user` is not either, but it is frequently added to the `request` object in the middelware by looking at the session).

You thus need to *encode* it into the URL, or in the `POST` parameters. For example with:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import like_shop

urlpatterns = [
    path('shop/<int:shop_id>/like', like_shop, name='like_shop'),
]
```

Then in the view we obtain a parameter `shop_id` that contains the `id` of the related `Shops` object:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from app.models import Shops

def like_shop(request, shop_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        shop = get_object_or_404(Shops, id=shop_id)
        form = LikeShopForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            u = form.save(commit=False)
            u.user = request.user
            u.shop = shop
            u.save()
            return redirect('shops')
    else:
        form = LikeShopForm()
    return render(request, "shops.html", {'form': form, 'shop_id': shop_id})
```

Then the request in the POST should point to:

```
<!--  shops.html -->

<form action="{% url 'like_shop' shop_id=shop_id %}" method="post">
  <!--  ... -->
</form>
```

The URL to this page then thus looks like `/shops/123/like` with `123` the `id` of the shop. If you thus want to pass the shop "implicitly", you need to encode it in the URL. Otherwise, you should make it a field of the form, such that the user can pick an option. Personally I find it very strange that you use `date_posted` as a form field, since typically this is an field that I would expect to be filled in with the timestamp when the user likes the shop.

> **Note**: the name of the models is normally *singular*, so `Shop` instead of `Shops`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I like your solution, but I have a view that contain all shops not only one, and the user could like or dislike anyone he wants, so my qst is how can I know the shop_id that the user liked/disliked within all the shops
another thing is, in the form, I only want the submit button to be shown, so I didn't mentioned any field but it gave me an error, so I just used the date and I don't know how to hidden it

Comment: @F.F.: I think then you should actually make a `<form>` *per* shop so to speak. So if you iterate over the `{% for shop in object_list %}`, you can make a form like `<form method="post" action="{% url 'like_shop' shop_id=shop.id }"><input type="submit" value="like"></form>`. After all the server does not really know much abotut the page submitted before.